# Java layouts not updating component size when custom button changes text

Tags: java, swing, button, layout

I am making a button where when you click on it it changes the text. But when I click on the button and change the text, the button does not change size according to the text. Instead, it gets smaller and attempts to make that "..." thing when it does not have enough room. Here is my code:

Text.java

```
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.add(panel);
        final CButton button = new CButton("");
        panel.add(button);
        button.addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                button.setText(button.getText()+"f");
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {

            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {

            }
        });
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

CButton.java

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.ComponentListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.geom.Area;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class CButton extends JButton implements ComponentListener, KeyListener {
    protected static final int BORDER_WIDTH = 5;
    private static final Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 30);
    private static final Insets INSETS_MARGIN = new Insets(2, 5, 2, 5);

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected Area m_areaDraw = null;
    private Area m_areaFill = null;

    private double m_dHeightDraw = 0d;
    private double m_dHeightFill = 0d;
    private double m_dWidthDraw = 0d;

    private double m_dWidthFill = 0d;
    private int m_nMinHeight = 0;
    private int m_nMinWidth = 0;

    private int m_nStringHeightMax = 0;
    private int m_nStringWidthMax = 0;
    private RoundRectangle2D m_rrect2dDraw = null;
    private RoundRectangle2D m_rrect2dFill = null;
    private Shape m_shape = null;

    public CButton(String strLabel) {
        super(strLabel);
        setContentAreaFilled(false);
        setMargin(CButton.INSETS_MARGIN);
        setFocusPainted(false);
        addComponentListener(this);
        addKeyListener(this);
        // Determine the buttons initial size
        setFont(CButton.font);
        Frame frame = JOptionPane.getRootFrame();
        FontMetrics fm = frame.getFontMetrics(getFont());
        m_nStringWidthMax = fm.stringWidth(getText());
        m_nStringWidthMax = Math.max(m_nStringWidthMax,
                fm.stringWidth(getText()));
        // WARNING: use getMargin. it refers to dist btwn text and border.
        // Also use getInsets. it refers to the width of the border
        int nWidth = Math.max(m_nMinWidth, m_nStringWidthMax + getMargin().left
                + this.getInsets().left + getMargin().right
                + this.getInsets().right);
        m_nStringHeightMax = fm.getHeight();
        // WARNING: use getMargin. it refers to dist btwn text and border.
        // Also use getInsets. it refers to the width of the border
        int nHeight = Math.max(m_nMinHeight, m_nStringHeightMax
                + getMargin().left + this.getInsets().left + getMargin().right
                + this.getInsets().right);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(
                nWidth + ((2 * getFont().getSize()) / 5), nHeight
                        + ((2 * getFont().getSize()) / 5)));
        // Set the initial draw and fill dimensions
        setShape();
    }

    @Override
    public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {
    }

    // Needed if we want this button to resize
    @Override
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
        m_shape = new Rectangle2D.Float(0, 0, getBounds().width,
                getBounds().height);
        m_dWidthFill = (double) getBounds().width - 1;
        m_dHeightFill = (double) getBounds().height - 1;
        m_dWidthDraw = ((double) getBounds().width - 1)
                - (CButton.BORDER_WIDTH - 1);
        m_dHeightDraw = ((double) getBounds().height - 1)
                - (CButton.BORDER_WIDTH - 1);
        setShape();
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(int nX, int nY) {
        if ((null == m_shape) || m_shape.getBounds().equals(getBounds())) {
            m_shape = new Rectangle2D.Float(0, 0, this.getBounds().width,
                    this.getBounds().height);
        }
        return m_shape.contains(nX, nY);
    }

    // This is so the button is triggered when it has focus
    // and we press the Enter key.
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if ((e.getSource() == this) && (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)) {
            doClick();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    };

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    };

    @Override
    public void paintBorder(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        RenderingHints hints = new RenderingHints(
                RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setRenderingHints(hints);
        g2.setColor(Color.black);
        Stroke strokeOld = g2.getStroke();
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(CButton.BORDER_WIDTH,
                BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND));
        g2.draw(m_areaDraw);

        if (getModel().isRollover()) {
            g2.setColor(Color.GRAY);
            g2.draw(m_areaDraw);
        }
        g2.setStroke(strokeOld);
    };

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        RenderingHints hints = new RenderingHints(
                RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setRenderingHints(hints);
        if (getModel().isArmed()) {
            g2.setColor(Color.CYAN.darker());
        } else {
            g2.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        }
        g2.fill(m_areaFill);
        super.paintComponent(g2);
    }

    private void setShape() {
        // Area
        double dArcLengthFill = Math.min(m_dWidthFill, m_dHeightFill);
        m_rrect2dFill = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(0d, 0d, m_dWidthFill,
                m_dHeightFill, dArcLengthFill, dArcLengthFill);
        // WARNING: arclength and archeight are divided by 2
        // when they get into the roundedrectangle shape
        m_areaFill = new Area(m_rrect2dFill);
        // Border
        double dArcLengthDraw = Math.min(m_dWidthDraw, m_dHeightDraw);
        m_rrect2dDraw = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(
                (CButton.BORDER_WIDTH - 1) / 2, (CButton.BORDER_WIDTH - 1) / 2,
                m_dWidthDraw, m_dHeightDraw, dArcLengthDraw, dArcLengthDraw);
        m_areaDraw = new Area(m_rrect2dDraw);
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(String strText) {
        super.setText(strText);
        int nWidth = Math.max(m_nMinWidth, m_nStringWidthMax + getInsets().left
                + getInsets().right);
        int nHeight = Math.max(0, getPreferredSize().height);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(nWidth, nHeight));

        m_dWidthFill = getBounds().width - 1;
        m_dHeightFill = getBounds().height - 1;

        if ((m_dWidthFill <= 0) || (m_dHeightFill <= 0)) {
            m_dWidthFill = (double) getPreferredSize().width - 1;
            m_dHeightFill = (double) getPreferredSize().height - 1;
        }

        m_dWidthDraw = m_dWidthFill - (CButton.BORDER_WIDTH - 1);
        m_dHeightDraw = m_dHeightFill - (CButton.BORDER_WIDTH - 1);

        setShape();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call

```
setPreferredSize(new Dimension(
    nWidth + ((2 * getFont().getSize()) / 5), nHeight
    + ((2 * getFont().getSize()) / 5)));
```

in the constructor, but never change it. This means that each time the layout manager asks the component what size it would like to be, it always gets the same value.

A preferred solution would be to override getPreferredSize and calculate the size there, if it's not to complicated or time consuming

The next question is why are you going to all this extra effort.  Basically, you should simply allow the parent `JButton` to provide its preferred size and add your requirements around it, or simply use the `margins` properties or even a `Border`

You're `KeyListener` also seems useless as this is the default behaviour of the button anyway and in any case, key bindings would be a preferred solution

Comment: Thank you, this fixed the problem. I did remove the KeyListener part as that wasn't needed in the first place. I stole this code from another website.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was that it had to do with your humongous `CButton` implementation. At least, copy/paste of your code created a working application. That's a big plus in my book.

When I simply replaced the strange `nWidth` calculation in the `setText()` method with:

```
int nWidth = 100;
```

The size was increased after a click and showed an "f", which I assume is what you wanted.

So, I can't really say how to calculate the width, but at least you know where to look and which line to change.

Comment: I wanted the button to adjust to the size of the text, not a fixed size.